# Position Of String Using StringFormat

Tags: c#, controls, string-formatting

Is there a way to get the position of a drawn string in a control? I'm writing a control that acts as a GroupBox and I when I draw the string that acts as the title, the border line strikes through it.
[image]

In order to fix this problem, I was just going to fill and rectangle where the title is with a back color so the title doesn't appear to be struck through. My problem is that the position of the title is dictated by the StringFormat I pass through the Graphics.DrawString() method. I don't have to explicitly declare the location of the string, but I do have to explicitly declare the location of the rectangle and I don't know where the location of the string is.

How should I go about this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe you can use `MeasureCharacterRanges` to accurately measure string position

here is a little sample:

The method for doing measurement:

```
public static RectangleF MeasureStringBounds(Graphics graphics, string text, Font  font,RectangleF bounding, StringFormat format)
{
    var ranges =new[] {new CharacterRange(0, text.Length)};

    format.SetMeasurableCharacterRanges(ranges);

    var regions = graphics.MeasureCharacterRanges(text, font, bounding, format);
    var accurateBoundings = regions[0].GetBounds(graphics);

    return accurateBoundings;
}
```

Usage:

```
protected override void OnPaint(PaintEventArgs e)
{
    base.OnPaint(e);

    var str = "hello";
    var format = new StringFormat {Alignment = StringAlignment.Center};

    e.Graphics.DrawString(str, Font, new SolidBrush(Color.Black), new Rectangle(0, 0, Width, Height), format);

    //measuring part
    var region = MeasureStringBounds(e.Graphics, str, Font, new RectangleF(0, 0, Width, Height), format);
    //Draw measured region
    e.Graphics.DrawRectangle(new Pen(Color.Red), region.X, region.Y, region.Width, region.Height);
}
```